How to prove to agda that there is a number that has more divisors than the given one
How does agda proof logic works in case of program termination? Is there a way to prove odds in agda?
I would like to proof that for any number n there is a number m such that the number of divisors of m is greater than the number of divisors of n.
I'm trying to solve a Euler problem №12 about finding the first triangular number to have over 500 divisors. I have implemented this algorithm in Agda, but I've got an error message about program termination. As I get Agda just has no proof that ((numberOfDivisors ∘ triangleNumber) n) > 500 will ever succeed. Is there some way to proof that it will happen or probably a way this problem could be rewritten?
natRange : Nat → List Nat
natRange zero = []
natRange (suc n) = n ∷ natRange n

numberOfDivisors : Nat -> Nat
numberOfDivisors n = (length ∘₂ filterᵇ) (λ {zero → false ; x@(suc _) → n % x == zero}) (natRange (suc n))

-- get a triangular number
triangleNumber : Nat -> Nat
triangleNumber zero = zero
triangleNumber (suc n) = suc n + triangleNumber n


-- recursive algorithm
findTriangleNumberRecursively : (trNum : Nat) .{{_ : NonZero trNum}} → Nat
findTriangleNumberRecursively n = 
    if ((numberOfDivisors ∘ triangleNumber) n) < 500
        then findTriangleNumberRecursively (suc n)
    else triangleNumber n

main : IO ⊤
main = (putStrLn ∘ show) (findTriangleNumberRecursively (suc zero))

Error message
Termination checking failed for the following functions:
  findTriangleNumberRecursively
Problematic calls:
  findTriangleNumberRecursively (suc n)


NonZero constraint is redundant here, and Agda likely failed to resolve it. Agda doesn't implicitly resolve such constraints unless you provide an explicit proof that trNum is non-zero
